# How to use or condition in group by having clause

Tags: php, mysql

How we can use OR condition in group by clause below is my sql query

```
SELECT count(id) as num_rows, 
        (3959 * acos ( cos ( radians(41.766908)) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(-81.1526976)) + sin ( radians(41.766908) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ))) AS distance
FROM (`items`) 
WHERE `status` = 1 
GROUP BY `distance` 
HAVING `distance` <=50
```

In this query I have to add **OR** condition as well with group by clause that is

```
 (GROUP BY `distance` HAVING `distance` <=50 OR `nationwide`=1)
```

How we can execute above query ??

Below is my result - and I have to add OR condition in having by clause

**id    nationwide  distance**

1      2        22.4347083649522

1     2       46.8127635462102

8     2         10.0201103523007

13    1      11.888890536392

Comment: why not `where nationwide=1` ?

Comment: @splash58 but what if `nationwide=0` and `distance` grater than 50 ?

Comment: nationwide is not calculated field so OP can use it in where clause while distance in having - `where nationwide=1 GROUP BY distance HAVING distance <=50`

Comment: Your question is confusing. You put `OR` is in the `HAVING` clause, not the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: You can have an `or` condition in the having clause as well, so I do not really understand your question!

Comment: `HAVING` is tested **after** grouping. But different rows in the same distance group can have different values of `nationwide`. Do you want to show a distance if **any** of the items at that distance are nationwide?

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the desired results?

Comment: Consider the case where there's 2 points with the same distance, with one having `nationwide=2` and the other `nationwide=1` what would your expected outcome be?

Comment: @apokryfos it should be either distance will be less than or equal to 50 or nationwide should be equal to one

Comment: @splash58 I have to put OR condition either distance should be less than 50 or by nationwide should be 1

Comment: @sam You are missing the fact that when you `GROUP BY` each result row potentially contains details for more than one table row.

Comment: @sam make union - `(select id nationwide distance where nationwide=1) union (your query (maybe, with where nationwide <>1)) group by distance `

Comment: Just to be clear, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` are **separate** (though often used together) clauses; normally I would just assume the title was for brevity rather than stemming from misunderstanding but your parenthesis seem to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Probably it will help you

```
GROUP BY `distance`(HAVING `distance` <= 50 OR `nationwide` = 1);
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how this works? I still don't know how it would behave if there's 2 rows both with distance e.g. 70 and one having `nationwide = 1` and the other one having `nationwide = 2`. The grouping operator will group them both together because the distance is the same.

Comment: First, it will check distance<= 50 if not then it will check nationwide = 1 if yes then it will return that row. As in your example, it will return first row.

Comment: But `nationwide` is defined on a single row, not a group of rows

Comment: Not sure why you've used the parenthesis that way. But more importantly, this will give inconsistent results. Since nationwide is not part of the `group by` the value used in the `having` will be an arbitrary one chosen from the rows that had that distance.

Comment: @apokryfos your assumption int he first comment under this answer is correct; my above comment explains what will happen in just such a case.

Comment: @Anandjain it will not return the "first row", by the time having is evaluated the separate source rows are no longer in scope, only the grouped results.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY `distance`, `nationwide`
HAVING `distance` <= 50 OR `nationwide` = 1
;
```

Note this will GROUP the `COUNT`s by both field values; if you want the count of all where nationwide = 1 and the count of all where distance >= 50 separately, you will need two separate queries... and a UNION really wouldn't make sense, since distance will be irrelevant in the first, and nationwide irrelevant in the latter.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a comma (,)

(GROUP BY `distance` HAVING `distance` <=50, `nationwide`=1)